# solr >4.6 support in datastax enterprise edition

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

this is more a support question, but when is DSE support Solr >4.6 ? From solr 4.7 deep pagination in solr is supported, which would be great to see supported by DSE as well.

Best,
Ramo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly coming since it's part of Solr, but we don't give any guidance as to the timing or specific content of future DSE releases.